# OpenCV's matchShapes always returns 0

Tags: opencv

I'm using `matchShapes` to recognize some basic contours. However, it's returning 0, no matter what contours I compare...

Template images:

[image: circle]
[image: cross]
[image]

Examplary input image:

[image: empty triangle, empty circle, cross]

The code:

```
using std::vector;
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

findContours(binary, contours, hierarchy,
             CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_KCOS);

drawContours(binary, contours, -1, Scalar(255, 255, 255));

if (!contours.size()) // avoid sigsegv
    return;

for (int idx = 0; idx >= 0; idx = hierarchy[idx][0]) {
    double bestMatch = INFINITY;
    int bestI = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < knownContours.size(); i++) {
        vector<Point>& a = knownContours[i].contour;
        vector<Point>& b = contours[idx];
        std::cout << "a.size = " << a.size() << ", b.size = " << b.size() << std::endl;
        double match = matchShapes(b, a, CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I1, 0);
        std::cout << "idx=" << idx << " ? " << knownContours[i].name << " = " << match << std::endl;
        if (bestI == -1 || match < bestMatch) {
            bestI = i;
            bestMatch = match;
        }
    }
}
```

(`knownContours` are obviously initialized with template image data: `imread()`, then `findContours()`, finally `this->contour = contours[0]`).

And resulting output (a fragment):

```
-- new frame
a.size = 57, b.size = 74
idx=0 ? circle = 0
a.size = 80, b.size = 74
idx=0 ? cross = 0
a.size = 45, b.size = 74
idx=0 ? triangle = 0
a.size = 57, b.size = 60
idx=1 ? circle = 0
a.size = 80, b.size = 60
idx=1 ? cross = 0
a.size = 45, b.size = 60
idx=1 ? triangle = 0

-- new frame
a.size = 57, b.size = 75
idx=0 ? circle = 0
a.size = 80, b.size = 75
idx=0 ? cross = 0
a.size = 45, b.size = 75
idx=0 ? triangle = 0
a.size = 57, b.size = 57
idx=1 ? circle = 0
a.size = 80, b.size = 57
idx=1 ? cross = 0
a.size = 45, b.size = 57
idx=1 ? triangle = 0

-- new frame
a.size = 57, b.size = 76
idx=0 ? circle = 0
a.size = 80, b.size = 76
idx=0 ? cross = 0
a.size = 45, b.size = 76
idx=0 ? triangle = 0
a.size = 57, b.size = 51
idx=1 ? circle = 0
a.size = 80, b.size = 51
idx=1 ? cross = 0
a.size = 45, b.size = 51
idx=1 ? triangle = 0
```

So the sizes of compared contours differ (so the contours differ), yet `match == 0` always. What's going on here?

***Edit:*** OpenCV version is 2.4.9 (cloned & built yesterday).

Comment: Are you sure that `vector<Point>& a = knownContours[i].contour;` is correct? I guess that `knownContours` is `vector<vector<Point>>`, what is the `.contours` for?
Try to print or display this contour to see, whether the contour is actually correct.

Comment: @elactic, the problem exists in 2.4.9 only, see my answer.

Comment: Oh i had never thought of this ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to a bug in OpenCV 2.4.9.

On 2.4.5 (stable) this works fine.

See [this post on OpenCV Answers](http://answers.opencv.org/question/14804/matchshapes-always-returns-0/?answer=14817#post-id-14817).